# Adding www to all links .Net

Tags: asp.net, redirect, url-rewriting

I write this code in the `Application_BeginRequest`

```
if (!Request.IsLocal && Request.Url != null && !Request.Url.ToString().Contains("www."))
{
    string requestedUrl = Request.Url.ToString();

    Response.Redirect(requestedUrl.Replace("http://", "http://www.").Replace("https://", "https://www."));
}
```

Is there any better way to do that?

Comment: What's going to happen if you have a sub-domain? `http://media.mysite.com`

Comment: You could try regular expressions, they have the ability to find and replace given a certain criteria.

Comment: @Josh what happens if it has a sub-domain ? http://www.media.mysite.com works I think.

Comment: If you're doing this for SEO purposes, don't bother, specify a [canonical url](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) instead

Comment: @Basic Thanks for the information. This is not SEO purpose. The urls occurs SSL errors without www.

Comment: @Ryu: is this a site that you have deployed?

Comment: @Mike I have a ftp permission. But I am not able to configure IIS or remoting server desktop cause no permission

Comment: You're not accounting for urls like... `http://mydomain.com/User/Login.aspx?ReturnTo=http://www.mydomain.com` - This wouldn't be rewritten as it contains `www.` even though it's not where you meant it to be. If I were you, I'd set up 2 sites, one on `www.mydomain.com` and one on `mydomain.com` - The site on `mydomain.com` would only serve a 301 redirect to `https://www.mydomain.com/[Duplicated url]`